Why are the YAML highlight options not being reflected in my HTML that is knitted from and RMD?
I am working in r studio. For my college class, we're working in rmd files and then knitting them to html files. Each rmd file starts with YAML options that setup the document. The document has no problem being rendered independent of the highlighting style I choose. The theme: cerulean option works, and changes are reflected in my document when I switch to theme: journal. However, I would like to be able to change the highlight options for the whole document. No matter what I have listed, either 'tango', 'kate', 'monochrome' or even just deleting the highlight option entirely, the appearance of the highlighted text in the HTML does not change.
I also can't seem to find examples of what the highlighting options should look like through internet searches. It is likely that I'm not searching for the right thing because I can't imagine that there aren't any examples online given the vastness of the internet.
This is the YAML code that I have at the top of my document:
---
title: "Chi Squared Test"
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: cerulean
    highlight: tango
    code_folding: hide
---

This is an example of the rmd text with some highlighted words using backticks to select the words I want highlighted:
"data makes use of two column names being POLVIEWS and DIVORCE"
I have tried these things with no success:

Cleared knitr cache
updated everything using update.packages() and also running install.packages('rmarkdown')
Restarted r studio and reloaded the project.
Restarted my computer.
Ensured that everything in my r studio files is accessible and up-to-date.

Any help is welcome.
EDIT:
I also checked and updated the pandoc version, it is running on 3.1.11
